# Best way to create global variables that are accessible from both client (jquery) and server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create global variables for a given session that are accessible from the client side jquery script and server side and from any page.

The best way I've come up with so far is to pass my model around. When I go from controller to view I pass the model the normal way:

```
return View(model);
```

Inside my cshtml page I load the model into a local jquery object:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

As users make changes I can reflect those changes in my jquery object:

```
model.Name=$("#name").val();
```

Then when I go to a new page I pass the jquery object back to my server side model using json.

jquery

```
//convert model to json string
var strJson = JSON.stringify(model); 

//call another page and pass json string
window.location.href = "/Home/Test/?strJson=" + strJson;
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Test(string strJson)
{
    //convert json string back to model object
    ProjectModel model = new ProjectModel();
    model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ProjectModel>(strJson); 

    return View(model);
}
```

This method works pretty well but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I tried using the Session object but I had trouble accessing the Session object data from jquery. I wrote 2 ajax calls SetSession and GetSession to read and write variables to the server Session object but the GetSession is giving me a headache because of the fact that it's asynch. So if I do this it's out of order:

jquery

```
//calls a function that uses ajax to get the Session variable
var x = GetSession("Name");

alert(x); //undefined because this statement get executed before x is set
```

So I'm stuck at the moment using this idea (Session object).

Does anyone know a better way to do create globals that are accessible from jquery and the controller?

Comment: Do you really need to alter data in the session object from the View?? What about something like:
1) Fill a ViewModel with data  that you need from the session object and send that VM to the view.
2) Do whatever you want with that VM in the view and then send it back to controller via Submit() or an Ajax call.
3) Update the Session object In the controller from the VM object.

Comment: I thought I tried that and didn't like it for some reason. I've tried so many things I can't remember what I've tried! That sounds like a good idea though.